# Handling File Access when a file is in use

Tags: file-io

Since there's no way to reliably check if a file is in use before trying to access it, is it advisable to just make continuous attempts at moving/deleting/reading them until the action is succesful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this one helps... [it is in C#... and not the most elegant way of doing this, but still check it out] http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/FileInUse.aspx

Comment: Yeah. I was wondering about that. Is that really the only way to do it? XD And then looping around that until it gets it right.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language/operating system you're using.  Most languages have some sort of method to check if file is available for opening; another thing you can do is to try to open the file and catch the exception if it is open.  Finally, if you're solely intending to read from a file, you may be able to open it anyway.